# Automate MySQLdump to local computer (Windows)

Tags: windows, ssh, mysql, putty

I'd like to automate a mysqldump to my computer from a remote host, and I cannot figure out how to do it.

I suppose that I should run a mysqldump through an SSH tunnel, but this becomes complicated by the fact that my local computer is a Windows XP machine.  I'm using putty to open a tunnel like so:

```
putty -load "[my saved session]" -L [localport]:localhost:3306 -N
```

Note: I can't just connect to the mysql server remotely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP regular backup of mysql data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916163/php-regular-backup-of-mysql-data)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of PuTTY, download the command line version `plink.exe`.  Then using the same connection parameters you can run the mysqldump via plink and save the output locally.  PLink is available from the same download page as PuTTY.

```
# setup the tunnel with plink
plink -load "[my saved session]" -L [localport]:localhost:3306
# Mysqldump your local port, redirected to outfile
mysqldump --port=[localport]  -h localhost -uuser -ppassword dbname > outfile
```

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Or, another method would be to execute `mysqldump` in the same command line as `plink`, redirecting it to `outfile` on the local machine.

```
plink -load "[my saved session]" mysqldump -uuser -ppassword dbname > outfile
```

Comment: I'm trying (and failing) right now. <p>When I try the first approach, the dump doesn't appear to take place (as though the second command is waiting on the first to terminate).  When I terminate the connection, the outfile is created (but empty)  <p>As for the second approach, could you explain the latter args?  Is outfile just supposed to be filename (not path)?  What's pscp?  Why do I list the outfile for remote and local machines at the end? Is it redundant?

Comment: @JellicleCat `pscp.exe` is a secure copy (`scp`) utility downloaded from the same place as putty & plink.  Used for copying files via an ssh connection...

Comment: @JellicleCat Regarding the outfile args... `outfile` can either be just the filename so the dump occurs in whatever directory you happen to be in (probably /home/username) or a full path to where you want it to end up.  Then in the `pscp` command, the first arg is the ssh specification required to connect to the remote machine, followed after a colon by the path to the file.  Second arg is where you want the file to end up locally.  All of this also works with an SSH key if you have one setup.

Comment: Ah. Okay, I've downloaded it (and now realised that option 2 was 2 commands, not 1 command with a line wrap--silly of me).  Thanks so much.

Comment: @JellicleCat for some plink examples, see http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter7.html

Comment: Ah, sorry.  Next time I'll put comment lines in between.

Comment: I do not think the second solution does what a description says. The `>` is interpreted locally. So the `outfile` is created locally. No point/need downloading it with `pscp`. You have to wrap whole `mysqldump` command including the redirect to double-quotes to make it redirect to a remote file. See [my answer to similar (if not duplicate) question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28494574/850848).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl You're correct, I edited it according to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can automate this process by setting up two things with the help of crons

**1 You have to generate MYSQLDUMP on regular basis by creating a cron using below command on your remote machine.**

[MYSQLDUMP Command](http://www.oyewiki.com/mysql/mysql-dump-how-to-take-mysql-dump-export-mysql-data)

MYSQLDUMP -uuser -p --all-databases > file_name.sql

**2. You have to create a cron to transfer the file from remote server to your local machine using SCP Command that is mentioned below.**

[Linux SCP Command](http://www.oyewiki.com/linux/linux-unix-scp-command)

scp user@remote_ip:~/mysql_dump_file_name.sql ./

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (one line code in myBackup.bat file):

> mysqldump --result-file=C:\myProject\dbDump.dump --port=21
>
> --host=localhost --user=dbUser --password=dbPassword dbName | plink -L 21:localhost:3306 -ssh mysshUser@domain.com -pw mysshPassword   >
>
> C:\myProject\dbDump.log

Answer (score 0):

Building on what @Michael Berkowski gave me (and adapting to Linux, which is now all I use), I end up with two commands for tunneling to **Server A** to access a MySQL server on **Server B**:

```bash
ssh -f -L [localPort]:[serverB]:[serverB_mysqlPort] --port [serverA_sshPort] user@serverA -N
mysqldump -u[user] -p[password] -P[localPort] -h 127.0.0.1 [databaseName] > outfile
```