# mysqldump from remote host

Tags: mysql, linux, ssh

Is it possible to dump a database from a remote host through an ssh connection and have the backup file on my local computer.

If so how can this be achieved?

I am assuming it will be some combination of piping output from the ssh to the dump or vice versa but cant figure it out.

Comment: I have replied to similar answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564882/automate-mysqldump-to-local-computer-windows/13584425#13584425

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This would dump, compress and stream over ssh into your local file

```
ssh -l user remoteserver "mysqldump -mysqldumpoptions database | gzip -3 -c" > /localpath/localfile.sql.gz
```

Answer (score 21):

Starting from @MichelFeldheim's solution, I'd use:

```
$ ssh user@host "mysqldump -u user -p database | gzip -c" | gunzip > db.sql
```

Answer (score 3):

`ssh -f user@server.com -L 3306:server.com:3306 -N`

then:

`mysqldump -hlocalhost > backup.sql`

assuming you also do not have mysql running locally. If you do you can adjust the port to something else.

Comment: I need this in a single command though thats why i thought there would be a combination of pipes

Comment: Is this opening a tunnel on the specified port? Didn't see this approach yet

Comment: @Feldheim yes creates a tunnel which all communications will be encrypted. As for the best answer for this question I like your approach. You get my upvote.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a [script](https://github.com/loganstellway/mysqldump-remote) to make it easier to automate `mysqldump` commands on remote hosts using the answer provided by [Michel Feldheim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1032504/michel-feldheim) as a starting point:

> [mysqldump-remote](https://github.com/loganstellway/mysqldump-remote)

The script allows you to fetch a database dump from a remote host with or without `SSH` and optionally using a `.env` file containing environment variables.

I plan to use the script for automated database backups. Feel free to [create issues](https://github.com/loganstellway/mysqldump-remote/issues) / [contribute](https://github.com/loganstellway/mysqldump-remote) - hope this helps others as well!